# Drupal: customizing user registration workflow for communicating with another webapp

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm new to Drupal6 and spent long time searching how to implement the following feature without success: I use Drupal as front-end/doc board for a web-app. I want to mirror all user account creation, update and deletion on this web-app, i.e. send user name and password.

I started coding a little module implementing `hook_user` (http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_user/6), but I am still wondering on several question concerning this hook:

1) I can't find a doc concerning the `$account` fields, and thus don't know how to retrieve the user name and password.
2) The `insert` operation informs that "The user account is being added". Is that triggered when the user query an account or when his/her pending account creation has been approved?
3) User management on the 'slave' webapp is done through a URL interface. I only know the `header("Location: http://webapp/users/add?user=martin&pwd=bla")` PHP primitive, but I fear this will make a redirection, instead of just hiting the target page and continue code flow. Any suggestion?

Maybe some of you already programmed such a module, or would have links for more documentation?
Thanks in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final piece of code that works. Note that the password is retrieved md5ified, so the slave webapp must be able to do so as well:

```
function mirror_registration_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
 $cmd = 'http://www.example.com/register?name='.$account->name.'&pass='.$account->pass;

 if($op == 'insert'){
$cmd .= '&op=insert';
drupal_http_request( $cmd );
 }
 else if($op == 'delete'){
$cmd .= '&op=delete';
drupal_http_request( $cmd );
 }
 else if($op == 'after_update'){ // 'update' is a "before update event"
$cmd .= '&op=update';
drupal_http_request( $cmd );
 }
}
```

Remark: in our case, registration requires admin approval. In this case, there's an 'update' event. The 'insert' event is triggered as soon as the user queries an account.

Informations for other newbies:

When trying to debug the code, one can echo $cmd to have the content of $cmd writen on top left of the following page.

If you write crapy php code and get a blank page when using the hook, you may add to Drupal/index.php the following calls: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE); that allow having debug info.

Comment: Rather than modifying index.php, you can add those php settings to your site's settings.php.  It will be run as the first part of loading drupal, so unless you change any core files you won't miss any errors.  This way you may be less likely to accidentally turn on error reporting on a live site.  Installing XDebug on your development machine is also an excellent way to track down errors, since you can get the full call stack with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a step back and looking at the big picture, you have several options.

1. Use OpenID (there's a core Drupal module for it) for both sites
2. Use LDAP (there's a really good Drupal contrib module for it)
3. Look at other modules offer user login sharing with other apps (such as http://drupal.org/project/phpbb or http://drupal.org/project/moodle or many others) for inspiration
4. Have your web app use Drupal's user table. This is relatively easy as the username is there in plaintext and the password is just MD5'ed (so no salts or anything to muddy up the waters).

Comment: It sounds like he isn't in control of the web app or he wouldn't need the URL login route.

Comment: @Chris: I have control over the web app but want to minimize changes :)
@MCrittenden: Thanks for all these suggestions. OpenID and LDAP libraries implied too much changes for me. Phpbb and moodle provided some examples. I was fan of the direct user's table access, but unfortunately, the tables of my slave webapp are in another database, so a trigger can't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, hook_user is wrong.  What you need to do is use hook_form_alter to change the '#validate' parameter of the login form.  That way, the validate is passed to your function in your module where you are getting $form_values['username'] and $form_values['password'].  You pass that on to your URL via [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).  If it returns correctly, return nothing.  If it doesn't return, use form_set_error and it will deny the login.

Good luck!

Comment: Hook_user would be correct for adding/updating/deleting account information, but validating their login would require hook_form_alter

Answer (score 0):

In order to just retrieve a response from a page, you can use [drupal_http_request()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_http_request/6)

And a general security note, make sure you're authenticating and validating the requests between applications.  Passing passwords in plain text via GET parameters over HTTP also makes me a little queasy, but I don't know your application set up.

Comment: Good remark. The thing is that hook_user provides the password md5ified already.
drupal_http_request has been a good companion for this script, so thanks.